# Linux High Availability

Tags: linux, high-availability, heartbeat

I have two Linux Active/Passive nodes on which i have the same simple processing application(not webapp). I just need to have a HA cluster when one machine is down the application on the second takes the job. I don't want that both application runs at the same time. I need someting like Node A is down, Node P notices that, the P becomes the A then begins to process.

How can i do it ?

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

Heartbeat would work perfectly. You can also pair it up with DRBD to ensure that data is kept synchronised.

There is a good guide on How To Forge for an NFS server, but you can change it to suit whatever app you are running. The `ha.d` and `resource.d` dirs will allow you to execute your own start/stop failover scripts.

See:

1. http://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_nfs_drbd_heartbeat
2. http://www.howtoforge.com/high_availability_heartbeat_centos
3. http://www.howtoforge.com/openfiler-2.3-active-passive-cluster-heartbeat-drbd-with-offsite-replication-node

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's `Heartbeat`, or nowadays called `Corosync` exactly for that. With two nodes it's very simple to set up.

Take a look at [Linux-HA page](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page) and get back here if you do have something to ask.